# Finding algebraic expression for local minimum of a function with one unassigned variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the local minimum in the region `0.5<x<=1` of a function which has an unassigned variable `r` (note: `r` is always a positive integer).

I can make `FindMinimum` work, but only provided I assign a specific value to `r`. For example:

```
FindMinimum[(1 + Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2*r)*x)/(1 + r)])/
(2 + 2*r) /. r -> 2, {x, 0.5}]
```

But how do I find the minimum in general terms, i.e., in the form `{x -> f[r]}` for some function `f`? Or is the issue that there isn't a systematic representation of this local minimum with changing `r`?

Note that, at least by eye, the local minimum of the original function does seem to converge for large `r`:

```
Plot[
 {
  (1 + Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2 r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2 r)/. r -> 1, 
  (1 + Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2 r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2 r)/. r -> 10, 
  (1 + Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2 r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2 r)/. r -> 100, 
  (1 + Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2 r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2 r)/. r -> 1000,
  (1 + Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2 r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2 r)/. r -> 10000
 },
  {x, 0.5, 1.05}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.05}, {-0.25, 0.05}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"r=1", "r=10", "r=100", "r=1,000", "r=10,000"}
]
```

**EDIT:**

To clarify, what I am really hoping for is:

1. To define the point on the `x` axis which the local minimum converges towards with increasing `r`
2. To find a definition in terms of `x` (defined at the point of convergence) and `r` of the value of the original function with increasing `r` - does the value of the minimum converge on a limit? And can it be defined algebraically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NMinimize

```
xsol[r_?NumericQ] :=x /. NMinimize[{(1 +Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2*r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2*r),0.5 <= x <= 1}   , x][[2]]
```

xsol is the function "x[r]" you are looking for

```
Plot[xsol[r] , {r, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 1 } ]
```

[image]

**addenum**
If I understand your comment right you're looking for the asymptotic minimum
of the family of curves `f[x,r],r -> \[Infinity]`? If yes

```
f[x_, r_] := (1 +Csc[(Pi*x)/(1 + r)]*Sin[(Pi*(1 + 2*r)*x)/(1 + r)])/(2 + 2*r)
```

the asymptode (plotted in red)  and its minimum can be evaluated

```
asym=Series[f[x, r], {r, Infinity, 0}] // Normal
min=FindMinimum[asym, x]
(*{-0.217234, {x -> 0.715148}}*)

Show[{Table[Plot[f[x, r] , {x, 0.5, 1}], {r, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 100, 1000,10000}}], Plot[Sinc[2 Pi x], {x, 0.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]},PlotRange ->{{0.5, 1}, {-.5, .5}},GridLines -> {{{x /. min[[2]], Red}}, {{min[[1]], Red}}}]
```

[image]

Perhaps that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Two follow-ups: (1) how would I then express `xsol` algebraically in terms of `x` and `r`? (2) I'm particularly interested in whether this function converges (looks likely!), and if so to what - how would I find out?

Comment: Hi @Ulrich Neumann, I have edited the original question to clarify what I'm looking for. Many thanks for your input; I'm already further ahead than I was!

Comment: @Richard Burke-Ward I edited my answer hoping it is the answer you 're looking for...

Comment: Amazing. Just one more question: is there a way to give the `x` value in terms of functions of rational numbers in the same that `asym` gives `Sin[2*Pi*x]/(2*Pi*x)`? (I'll mark as answered anyway, just, it would be great if there was a way...)

Comment: @Richard Burke-Ward I don't expect x to be rational. More details you might find  if you look for  *cardinal sine function*

Comment: OK. Much appreciated, Ulrich.